# Summarize price from items in dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm struggling with making the program to summarize price of the products.

```
prices_and_their_products = {
    "Apple": 1,
    "Water": 2,
    "Grape": 3
}
shopping_list = ['Apple', 'Water']
```

I want the program to print "3".

The code I was trying to do it:

```
total = 0
for particular_items in shopping_list:
    total += prices_and_their_products.get(particular_items)
    print(total)
```

I wont program to print the summary of products in "shopping_list". In this case: 3

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have now?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me the code you have now is fine. It does print 1 then 3 because `print` is indented inside of the for loop, so if you want it just to print 3 you could unindent the print statement so that it only runs after the loop.

```js
#!/usr/bin/env python

prices_and_their_products = {
    "Apple": 1,
    "Water": 2,
    "Grape": 3
}
shopping_list = ['Apple', 'Water']

total = 0
for particular_items in shopping_list:
    total += prices_and_their_products.get(particular_items)
print(total)
```

```html
<script src="https://modularizer.github.io/pyprez/pyprez.min.js"></script>
```

There are ways it could be made more concise if you wish byt using a list_comprehension and the builtin `sum` function. In some cases list_comprehensions come at the expense of readability, but this case is simple enough that it works pretty well. Try this runnable example!

```js
#!/usr/bin/env python

prices_and_their_products = {
    "Apple": 1,
    "Water": 2,
    "Grape": 3
}
shopping_list = ['Apple', 'Water']
cost = sum(prices_and_their_products[item_name] for item_name in shopping_list)
print(f"{cost=}")
```

```html
<script src="https://modularizer.github.io/pyprez/pyprez.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a small indentation bug in it. Your print statement should not be inside the for loop or it will print the total for each iteration of the loop.

```
prices_and_their_products = {
    "Apple": 1,
    "Water": 2,
    "Grape": 3
}
shopping_list = ['Apple', 'Water']

total = 0
for particular_items in shopping_list:
    total += prices_and_their_products.get(particular_items)
print(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

just take the print outside the loop :

```
total = 0
for particular_items in shopping_list:
    total += prices_and_their_products.get(particular_items)
print(total)
```